# can't execute (Error 2) when using forfiles

Tags: batch-file

I wanted a one liner to delete all files older than 14 days in certain folder.

This is my command

forfiles -px:\logs -s -m*.log -d-14 -c"CMD /C del @file"

but when executed it outputs "can't execute (error 2)" for every file it finds.
If the -c "CMD /c del @file " is omitted it works fine producing a list of files older than 14 days. I first thought it might be a permission issue; but any action on the file produces the same result and I am admin on the comptuer.

It is however a network share if that makes a diffrence.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of @file, and what is the current directory when you're running the code?

winerror.h says that error 2 is

```
#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND             2L
```

so I would try fully qualifying your path to the file that is getting deleted.

--EDIT:

which you can do by doing

```
forfiles -px:\logs -s -m*.log -d-14 -c"CMD /C del @path"
```

instead of

```
forfiles -px:\logs -s -m*.log -d-14 -c"CMD /C del @file"
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the command to forfiles -px:\logs -s -m*.log -d-14 -c"CMD /C del @PATH\@FILE" that seemed to work it seems like it was case sentive as well as @file did not work but @FILE did.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this:

```
set DP_DIR=C:\Scripts

forfiles -p%DP_DIR% -s -m*.exe -d-3 -c"cmd /c del \"@FILE""
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FORFILES v 1.1 from April 1998.

In my situation, if the @PATH or @FILE contains a path with a space in it, this will not be handled correctly. Paths with spaces require double quotes around it. Since the executing command in forfiles requires double quotes, this is what I use in my batch files. The 0x22 gets saved to batch file as double quotes. I find that explicitly surrounding the path and file with double quotes make for reliable processing of files.

```
forfiles -pC:\pictures\ -m*.jpg -d-30 -c"cmd /c echo del 0x22@PATH\@FILE0x22" > c:\temp\delold_pics.bat

call c:\temp\delold_pics.bat
```